# Referencing `this` in an object literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
const myObj = {
        reply(text: string, options?: Bot.SendMessageOptions)
        {
            return bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, text, { reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id, ...options });
        },
        replyMd(text: string, options?: Bot.SendMessageOptions)
        {
            return this.reply(text, { parse_mode: "Markdown" });
        }
};
```

However, when I call `replyMd`, then `this` is undefined. Why?

Comment: how are you calling replyMd?

Comment: Where you called replyMd method?

Comment: @NicholasTower `const { replyMd } = myObj; replyMd("someText", { someOptions: true });`

Comment: `const { replyMd } = myObj; replyMd("someText", { someOptions: true });` That will invoke it with no context, so `this` is set to the window object (in non-strict mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
const foo = {
  bar() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}
```

Calling `foo.bar()` logs

```
Object {bar: function bar()}
```

but

```
const {bar} = foo
bar()
```

logs `undefined`

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method) for a detailed explanation.

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is
>   called. [...] When a function is called as a method of an object, its this
>   is set to the object the method is called on.